# Jmeter Module Controller - Not reading CSV file fully

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I have test a plan with Module controller, where my "Thread Group" has a CSV and it'll read each line(as input) and proceed the next samplers. But if i control it over the module controller, i should disable the Thread Group. In this case, Samplers were reading only first line of the CSV and the test getting completed without reading any further lines in CSV. Which means test is running only one time as "Thread Group" is disabled where "Loop count:" selected as forever(Image-3).

My Requirement, with the Module controller, i should able to run the "Simple Controller 1" and it should process the each line of CSV data and proceed with further samplers. Like this, it should iterate until the EOF CSV.

How could i make it work...

[image: Thread Group Config]

[image: CSV COnfig]

[image: Test Plan]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Module *and* the Simple controller block would be executed. From your question it is also not clear what you exactly disabled. If you disabled the "Thread Group" controller than there is not much the script would do.

I am not sure how you configured the [module controler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller) but I miss the *[Test Fragment](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment) controller* in your script. So....

I would expect a setup similar to this (see example), so it is logically separated where you have your 'function block' and where it is being used. So the Thread group will run the Testfragment as it is called from the Module controller. This is mostly useful if you re-use parts in different places of your script.

If in your case this is your full script you don't need the module controller.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response.. ! I have edited my Question, Now i have added correct image of my test plan. In the image, disabled "Thread group" "loop count" is forever. So, if i disable this, its not reading CSV file completely. Please suggest...

Comment: Please try to reorganize as in my example. Don't use the thread group but the *test fragment*. So exchange your disabled "Thread Group" for "Test Fragment". The way you have defined it I am not sure the CSV is even properly used as it is not part of the controller you have configured. Which would explain your problem.